# How to combine for-yield loop with if/else construct

Tags: scala

I have an array

```
val d = Array(1,-1,23,-5,7,8,0,-9)
```

I divide all even numbers by 2

```
val index = for(i <- 0 until d.length if d(i)%2==0) yield d(i) / 2
```

I add all odd numbers by 1

```
val index = for(i <- 0 until d.length if d(i)%2==1) yield d(i) + 1
```

How can I combine the two operation in one step?

```
val index = for(i <- 0 until d.length) if(d(i)%2==0) yield d(i) / 2 else yield d(i) + 1
```

Then I get a syntax error

```
illegal start of simple expression
```

Comment: Try this one `val index = for(i <- d.indices) yield if(d(i)%2==0) d(i) / 2 else d(i) + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call multiple yields.
So try this:

```
val d = Array(1,-1,23,-5,7,8,0,-9)
val index = for(i <- 0 until d.length) yield (if(d(i)%2==0) d(i) / 2 else d(i) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very stright forward

```
for{ value <- d
value2  = if(value ÷2 == 0 ) value/2 else value+1
} yield value2
```

**Result**

```
Array(2,0,24,-4,8,4,0;-8)
```

Comment: This is not a guard, this is just a computed value in the `for` statement. It is also more verbose than putting the `if` after the `yield` .

Comment: what defines a guards ?

Comment: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-for-loop-embedded-if-statements-guards-scala

Comment: i dont  think it is verbose. it is simply performing filtering/guarding as permitted.

Comment: A guard is a condition that must apply for a value to be included in the next stage of the `for`. It turns into a `filter` operation on the collection.

Comment: @Tim need  not be. Guards can be used at single stage as well.  sorry to disagree with you .

Comment: Can you please share the defination that u mentioned anywhere on scala doc ? It will be helpful

Comment: You just need to read the link that you posted. A guard is a filter operation: it is a condition (`if`) that is use to filter out some values from the collection. It can't have a value or an `else` clause. Look at the examples in that article: there are no values following the `if` and no `else` clauses. Your expression does not filter out values, it just computes `value2` from `value`.That fact that this expression contains an `if` does not make it a guard.

Comment: On book programming scala, 2nd Edition , page number 218 , you can find such examples.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a single `yield` with an `if` expression after the `yield` (as noted in the comments)

But you don't need to iterate over the index, you can just iterate over the array directly:

```
for (v <- d) yield if (v%2 == 0) v/2 else v + 1
```

This is equivalent to a `map` call:

```
d.map(v => if (v%2 == 0) v/2 else v + 1)
```

You can also use `collect` for this:

```
d.collect {
  case v if v%2 == 0 =>
    v / 2
  case v =>
    v + 1
}
```